# Resolving a type without registering first - prism 4 and Untiy

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

First of all I would like to remark I am new with the concept of prism, DI and containers. I am looking on one of the code samples provided with the Prism Library:
The code simply injects a view with the "Hello World" string (in a TextBlock element) to a region in the shell.

When the application starts-up, it creates a new BootStrapper instance, which creates and initializes the shell:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement)this.Shell;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

        ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(HelloWorldModule.HelloWorldModule));
    }
}
```

My question refers to the method CreateShell(). I couldnt find nowhere in the supplied code (including not in a configuration file or any xaml file...) where do they register the type Shell, and even if it was registered - the supplies Shell class doesnt implement any interface... what is the meaning of resolving a specific type?
the Shell implementation:

```
public partial class Shell : UserControl
{
    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

This looks like a magic to me, so I tried to create my own type (MyType) and resolve it the same way:

```
Container.Resolve<MyType>();
```

By setting a breakepoint inside MyType constructor, I saw that it DID resolved MyType. Can somebody please explain to me how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These couple of threads should answer your question:

- http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=230051
- [Does unity just make clasess with out needing anything registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836611/does-unity-just-make-clasess-with-out-needing-anything-registered/3840280#3840280)

Additionally, if you are eager to get more detail into how Unity can do this, simple download Unity 2.0 and open the source code that is provided with the installer.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to register a type you want to resolve. You need to register the dependencies of a type, that you want to resolve. In this case, the Shell doesn't need any dependencies, so you can resolve it simply. But for an example (not really), if your shell getting an interface IService as a parameter, then you must register IService, before you resolve Shell.

Otherwise you will get Dependency Resolution Failed Exception. In Prism 4.1 it will be swallowed silently due to TryResolve.